# Iterative summation of output generated by a function in a for loop (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

My goal is to sum the output generated from a code iteratively.

The code below can accurately compute the hamming distance between two strings, but does not sum up the distances across multiple strings. See sample strings below:

```
w=['ground', 'joint']
c=['gnoufd', 'johnt']

def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    if len(s1)==len(s2):
        return sum(x1 != x2 for x1, x2 in zip(s1, s2))

for x,y in zip(w,c):
    for j in x:
        for k in y:
           l=hamming_distance(x, y)
    print l
```

The output of the above code is: `1` `2`
I tried using list comprehension, hoping I could get the output in a list and sum them up, but got erroneous output.

```
for x,y in zip(w,c):
    k=[hamming_distance(x,y) for j,k in zip(x,y)]
    print k
```

Desired output: 3---(the sum of the one and two above)

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Note: your `hamming_distance` function doesn't return anything if `len(s1) != len(s2)`, which in Python means the function returns `None`.  That's why you're getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'` errors -- you're trying to add an `int` to `None`.  You should probably decide what to do if `len(s1)` and `len(s2)` differ, and modify `hamming_distance` accordingly.  Or, if Hamming distances are only defined for equal-length strings, then you'll either have to make sure that you're only passing equal-length strings, or handle the `None`s explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment DSM, I'll trying using exception.

Comment: Rather than using exceptions, I think you need to look at how you're looping.  Your `for j in x: for k in y:` loop wouldn't only compare `ground` with `gnoufd` but with `johnt` too.

Comment: Hi DSM, thanks a lot for your observation.

Comment: @DSM, the loop won't compare ground with johnt because there are of different length. There is a condition in the function.

Comment: yeah, which is why it's returning `None`.  I mean that you're going to call the function on pairs where you know it's going to return None, because rather than looping over the ones you want to compare, you're looping over everything.

Comment: It works with map and list-len exceptions, but when the items of two lists are not the same in number, it ignores the extra items on the longer list. ie **w=['ground', 'joint', Round] 
c=['gnoufd', 'johnt']*** and compares only the first two (mapping).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this block:

```
for x,y in zip(w,c):
    for j in x:
        for k in y:
           l=hamming_distance(x, y)
    print l
```

you don't use `j` or `k`, so you can get rid of those loops.

```
for x,y in zip(w,c):
    l=hamming_distance(x, y)
    print l
```

This is more readily translated into a generator expression.

```
k = [hamming_distance(x, y) for x, y in zip(w,c)]
print k
print sum(k)
```

Output:

```
[2,1]
3
```

Comment: hi @ Kevin, thanks for the solution. The reason I used the for loop(j,k) is because I'm making use of a lists of strings in a list ie [['ground', 'joint'], ['the','johnt']], and i'm still getting error message:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use a list of strings in a list, then. Use two variables that are each a list of strings, just like your original problem stated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your `for` loop - just use `map` instead as such:

```
diff = map(hamming_distance, w, c)
# [2, 1]
print sum(diff)
# 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution John. Here is how my data structure looks like:w=[['ground', 'joint'], ['there','johnt']]
c=['gnoufd', 'johnt']. I got the following error message when I applied your solution using the data structure: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'